# How to dismiss 2 view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue need to support:

Assume, I have the controller A and View Controller B. The view controller A present view controller B. After that view controller B load content completed. At View controller B I have a button. 
How to dismiss both view controller when I touch event button touch up inside?

Here my code: At view controller A

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mainstoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerB *viewcontrollerB = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewcontrollerB"];
[self presentViewController:viewcontrollerB animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And code in view controller B

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchUpInside:(id)sender {
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];     
   }
```

Thanks for helping me. You will save my time. :)

Comment: you can do this.. But the 2 view controllers dismiss one by one . Is this ok??

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation. When your button pressed call delegate, and in delegate method implementation write following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegation on your ViewControllerB

On ViewControllerB.h do this

```
@protocol ViewControllerDismissDelegate;

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic) id<ViewControllerDismissDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol ViewControllerDismissDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)didViewControllerBDismiss;
@end
```

On ViewControllerB.m do this

```
// Button action
- (void)buttonDidClick {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didViewControllerBDismiss)]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self.delegate didViewControllerBDismiss];
    }
}
```

Learn more about delegates and data sources here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Comment: How to dismiss view controller A ? I want to dismiss both of views (A and B).

Comment: How did you present ViewControllerA?

Comment: At view controller A. I've init view controller by B. Something like that

`UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];

ViewcontrollerB *vcB = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewcontrollerB"];
            [self presentViewController:vcB animated:YES completion:nil];`